# Rubymine creating text files by default

Tags: rubymine

I am attempting to create a .rb file within Ruby, using these steps:

```
1. Create New File
2. Name new file "a"
3. Associate file to .rb filetype
```

This creates a file named "a" that works fine; however, when I rename this file to a.rb it immediately converts the file to a text file. Why is that?

I have been creating files this entire time by creating a new file and naming it "`a.rb`" from the start, and it automatically associates it to a ruby file. Now it just associates that naming to a text file and I have to leave off the `.rb` and manually assign the filetype later. What changed?

Answer (score 1):

FOR MAC USERS you can find the settings you need to fix this here:

RubyMine | Preferences | Editor | File Types

The above answer is correct – removing a.rb does solve the problem – and I realize that this question is two years old now… But having come across this problem today and not having been able to find a solution for the longest time, hopefully this will help someone else too. Default Settings under File does NOT have this tab in the current version of RubyMine on Macs, and it took me forever to find the tab where File Types is.